# IE with Google maps loads page after delay

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, internet-explorer, loading

I've got very strange behavior in IE10/11 (ASP.Net MVC5)
Steps:

1. Click on any link
2. Request is sent and "loading" icon appears
3. Loading" icon disappears, but nothing happens
4. After some delay page content suddenly appears

Here is demo video: http://screencast.com/t/3bLFEFAqF

I tried under debug and figured out that "Loading" icon disappears before Action is ended.
This is very confusing from userr's point of view.

There is no Ajax request, just simple  references.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** after some research I have found out that this was caused by using Google maps. I have created empty MVC project and added this line:

```
<script src='@(this.Request.Url.Scheme)://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&visual_refresh=true&libraries=geometry,visualization,places' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I got result as demostrated on the video. Don't know how to fix it!